# How to write regex to remove last parameter from a URL

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to create URL rewrite inbound rule for IIS to return the URL before a specific parameter.

Edited:  I should have stated the authProvider is always the last parameter.

Example:

```
http://localhost/WebAccess/Default.ashx?accessionNumber=009&authProvider=Bypass
```

I want to trim off &authProvider=Bypass from the end of the URL

I've tried:

```
.*(?=&authProvider)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test" enabled="true">
                    <match url="(.*)&amp;authProvider.+" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work & how do you call the regex? As a standalone it does match what you're describing. Also be aware that it could break if the parameter order changes: `http://localhost/WebAccess/Default.ashx?authProvider=Bypass&accessionNumber=009`

Comment: I am struggling to create a valid rule.  in IIS URL rewrite 2.0.  I find the pattern abit confusing.  Apparently, my regex finds the match but does not replace

Comment: That's why I'm asking for more code: how do you try to do the replace operation?

Comment: I'm using IIS URL rewrite 2.0 extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example that you have shown will match what you want, but not change the URL. The result of your match should have the matched string that you want as the result.

I think that the problem may be that you are trying to replace what you match, but since the forward lookup (`?=` is not part of the match result) when you do the replace you are ending up with the same string as when you started. As an alternative, assuming that you are aware that this will not be very robust if parameter orders change, you could use:

```
(.*)&authProvider.+
```

Then replace with

```
$1
```

This will result in:

```
http://localhost/WebAccess/Default.ashx?accessionNumber=009
```

Essentially it matches the whole string and replaces it with everything before $auth, which is in group 1 (`$1`).

**Update**

With your update, I see that the rewrite rule syntax uses {R:1} so $1 should be {R:1} in my example and in your Rewrite Rule should be {R:1}. See [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module) for an example.

Comment: @GaryKindel - I think that you need to use {R:1} for the first group, see my update.